# Как вызвать из события поток с параметрами, заданными через класс C#?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, события

Доброе время суток.
Имеются срабатывающие в таймере событие, 3 потока и класс, передающий в поток 2 параметра (объект из очереди и время "эмуляции" работы с этим объектом).
Не могу сообразить, как создавать (вызывать?) потоки в момент срабатывания события (реализация события прописана в методе класса window).
Возможно, вы предложите более разумный вариант.

Код класса с параметрами:

```
public class Window
{
    private int blamkId; //для номера заявки
    private int timeBlankWork; //время "обработки" одной заявки (задерка для sleep)
    private bool isBusy1 = false;


    public Window(int x, int y) //конструктор
    {
        this.blamkId = x;
        this.timeBlankWork = y;
    }

    public void WinOption(int x, int y) //передаем нужные данные в поток
    {
        this.blamkId = x;
        this.timeBlankWork = y;
    }

    public int Wind1() //для обработки
    {
        isBusy1 = true; //установка флага в "занято"
        int BlankIdFin = blamkId;
        Thread.Sleep(timeBlankWork);
        isBusy1 = false;
        return BlankIdFin;
    }
    public void Message() //метод, вызываемый при срабатывании события
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test event");
    }

}
```

Код потока:

```
Window BigWin = new Window(0, 0); //создаем класс
BigWin.WinOption(WaitQue.Dequeue(), TimeBlankWork); //передаем параметры
Thread Work1 = new Thread(() => { result1 = BigWin.Wind1(); });
Work1.Start();
Work1.Join();
listBox1.Items.Insert(0, result1);
```

p.s. Сама идея - эмуляция СМО. Суть: таймер генерирует int x, отправляет его в очередь. Срабатывает событие, которое проверяет доступность одного из трех потоков. После "задержки", каждый поток возвращает результат в свой listbox.

Comment: Зачем вы делаете вызовы Start и Join подряд?

Comment: Странно, что для эмуляции СМО вы выбрали C# а не Smalltalk